Solving a heat equation, with puzzling passages.
I have the heat equation
$$
u_t=\frac{1}{2}u_{xx},\quad x\in \mathbb{R}\\
u(0,x)=x^2
$$
I tried to solve it with these passages:
$$u(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} G(t,x-y) \phi(y) dy$$
$$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{2t}}y^2dy$$
$$z=x-y \implies \frac{dz}{dy}=-1 \implies dy=-dz$$
$$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{\frac{-z^2}{2t}}(x-z)^2(-dz)$$
$$u(t,x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{\frac{-z^2}{2t}}(x^2-2xz+z^2)dz$$
$$u(t,x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2e^{\frac{-z^2}{2t}}  +\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (-2xz)e^{\frac{-z^2}{2t}} + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} z^2 e^{\frac{-z^2}{2t}} dz\right]$$
$$u(t,x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} [x^2\sqrt{2\pi t} - x\cdot 0 + t\sqrt{2\pi t}] $$
$$u(t,x)=-x^2-t $$
But, by substitution, this solution is not correct. I'm not sure of third integral. But also the sign is not correct.
Forgive me if text is not well-formatted. Could anyone so kind to give me correct passages?
Thanks in advance.

Notice that $\lim_{y\to\pm\infty}z=\mp\infty$, hence
\begin{align}
u(t,x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_{\color{red}{+}\infty}^{\color{red}{-}\infty} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2t}}(x-z)^2(-dz) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2t}}(x-z)^2\,dz.
\end{align}
Therefore, the final result is
$$
u(t,x)=x^2+t.
$$

Great....haven't noticed before! Thanks!
